# How to run 2 queries inside VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a simple VB.net program that I query an SQL database.  This program works fine, but I'd like to run 2 queries before closing the database connection... How can I do this without confusing the info from the 2 queries?

My code for the SQL portion looks like this:

```
Try
    For icounter = 1 To 2
        Call GetLocationInfo()
        connectionString = "Data Source=" & LocationDB & ";Initial Catalog=database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=login;Password=password"
        sql = "select count(sTicket_number) as tickets from tickets where dtcreated between @StartDate AND @EndDate"
        sqlCnn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

        sqlCnn.Open()
        sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sql, sqlCnn)
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", dtstartdate)
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", dtenddate)

        Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
        While sqlReader.Read()
            msgbox(sqlReader.Item(0))
        End While
        sqlReader.Close()
        sqlCmd.Dispose()
        sqlCnn.Close()
```

Comment: Use two sql commands? Also don't forget to accept and upvote answer(s) to your previous question.

Comment: at that point would it be "Sqlreader.item(1))"?

Comment: Well you did not specify which 2 commands you want to run, so I can only give general guidance. You currently have one `sqlCmd`. You can have as many as you want. Each can be separated into its own sub, where connection info is passed.

Comment: I suggest you use dataset object. Use a dataadapter to fill the dataset. You can query and name your datasets with different IDs before closing the connection. Plus you have much more easier control over rows using a dataset than the reader.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? `msgbox(sqlReader.Item(0))` You are not going to prompt a user for every query result, right? EDIT: actually, there can be only one in this case, but even then prompting the user is something you don't probably want.

Comment: No, I'll eventually change the code to the output I want.  I'm just trying to mess around with 2 queries in 1 connection.  I'll be connecting to 16 total databases at the end (icounter from 1 to 16).  So I need to keep the database connection open before closing it for each database.  I don't want to waste any time

Comment: Another side note, because you only have 1 result (count), **ExecuteScalar** should work much better for you. No need for reader then. You sub can become a function, returning count to `msgbox` (for now, in the testing phase).

Comment: Regarding time waste on connection open/close, SQL supports connection pooling, so even if you close a connection, it will keep it open for you. [See SQL Server Connection Pooling @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx). `When the application calls Close on the connection, the pooler returns it to the pooled set of active connections instead of closing it. Once the connection is returned to the pool, it is ready to be reused on the next Open call.`

Comment: Are you using MSSQL? If so, then you can create two Stored Procedures, define them into 2 SUBs and call them inside of your loop.

Comment: I would put all that into a SQLHelper class, then call your functions where you need them; less error prone, readability and reusable!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running only 2 queries I would move SqlCnn.Close()
outside of for loop.

and use

```
if SqlCnn.state=closed then
   SqlCnn.open()
endif
```

Comment: The loop is for connecting to 2 different databases.

Comment: @Shmewnix: So you want to run 2 queries, one against each database? Please add this information to the question - it's not obvious.

Comment: @Neolisk, No.  I want to run 2 queries for each database.  Above is the loop to run 1 query, on each database.  I want to run 2 queries for each database.

Comment: @Shmewnix: Oh okay, then my comment/answer/suggestion should work for you.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll break them into Sub's.  That should work just fine.